Citrus Integration Tests Framework - best approach for testing AWS DynamoDB operations
I am wondering what would be the best approach for testing AWS DynamoDB operations (preferably batchGetItem and batchWriteItem) using Citrus Integration Tests Framework.
I am currently using Citrus Framework version 4.0.1. For now, I have created a bean that handles the connection to DynamoDB, while in the integration test I have a Custom Action to call the insert/delete to/from DynamoDb. Something like this:
        $(context -> {
            // method call
        });

and I am looking for a way to validate the results (i.e. after a save method, I want to call another one to get the results from DynamoDb and the validate the size of the result list).
Any advise is appreciated.
Best regards,
Florin

Citrus also integrates well with Apache Camel and Camel provides very good AWS DDB support. So you can easily use Apache Camel components in Citrus to send/receive the data with AWS DDB and then use Citrus for the usual data verification.
Looks like this:
when(send(camel().endpoint(aws2Ddb("${table}").accessKey("${accessKey}")::getUri))
   .message(myAwsDdbRecord));

On the receiving side you could use a Camel route that leverages the AWS DDB Streams component from Camel. It automatically grabs new records and the test is able to verify the record data as usual.

Thank you very much Christoph for your answer. I will try it out and get back with feedback! :)
